# No type named 'time_zone' in namespace 'std::chrono'

Tags: c++, clang, mingw, c++20, c++-chrono

I'm trying to compile a project on windows under MinGW with Clang 16.0.4.

As a result, I get this error:
`error: no type named 'time_zone' in namespace 'std::chrono'`

In my CMakeLists I have this set:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set (CMAKE_C_STANDARD 17)
```

Also, I've tried changing that `gnu++20` to normal `c++20` standard with `CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF`, but this doesn't make any difference in the end.

What should I do? Maybe consider some non-standard replacement for time zones?

Comment: Do a verbose build, so you can see the actual commands used to build. Is the `-std=c++20` flag there? What standard library implementation is used? Have you installed the clang libc++, or are you using the MinGW GCC libraries? If you have installed libc++, are you using it, with the option `-stdlib=libc++`?

Comment: I've already checked the output and it indeed uses -std=c++20.
Also there is ` -stdlib=libc++ -lc++abi`.
And I'm using lates builds from here https://github.com/mstorsjo/llvm-mingw

Comment: `-stdlib=libc++` will definitely not work. `chrono::time_zone` isn't included in clang++16's standard library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `g++` 13 standard library to get `std::chrono::time_zone`. You most likely have an older version of the g++ standard library installed - which is what `clang++` uses by default.

The standard library provided by clang++16.0.4 itself (`-stdlib=libc++`) does not include `time_zone` either.

Options:

- Install a newer `g++` and make `clang++` use its standard library.
- Install [`date.h` + `tz.h`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) and use that.
- Build `clang++` and its standard library from the latest source. That includes `std::chrono::time_zone`.